# Interpretation of nabla followed by a dot (which is not meant as divergence)

Tags: calculus, analysis, physics, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I am studying a paper and the authors use $\nabla \cdot u$ for a real valued function $u\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and I am quite confused how to interpret that, even after long searches in books and the internet. They use this construct also for other real valued functions at other positions in the paper, therefore I think its not a mistake. Can anyone see what is meant by that(I have no background in physics, maybe there is such a notation in physics)? Since $u$ is real valued I hardly can interpret it as divergence.

Comment: It's another notation for the divergence: we think of nabla of as being a vector made of operators and then compute the dot product of this with the vector function

Comment: and how should I compute the divergence of a real valued function? I mean $n > 1$ in the above

Comment: You can apply the divergence to a vector field not to a scalar function! in which article did you find it?

Comment: As @alexjo says, it's probably a typo.

Comment: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2013/308616/ is a link to the article. You can find this on page 9 in equation (79) or on page 11 in equation (94) or at many other positions. To see that the $\nabla$ is not to depend on some expressions before it, you could look at page 11 equation (96), where this structure is an argument of the function $f$ given there. By the definition of $f$ in at this point, the divergence as an interpretations is also not suitable. It also occurs at many other positions so I think there should be another explanation than a typo.

Comment: They call it divergence after Equation 84. But from other parts of the paper it is clear that they apply it to function $R^N\to R $, so I agrew that something is wrong

Comment: But since they treat $ \nabla\cdot u $ to be real valued,  thus it cannot be the gradient either, making a typo less likely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they maybe could mean if $u({\bf x}) \in \mathbb R$, ${\bf x} \in \mathbb R^N$:

$$\nabla \cdot u = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_k}$$

i.e. expanding the scalar $u$ to all of the input dimensions and take divergence of the resulting field.

In other words:

$$\nabla \cdot (u {\bf 1}_N)$$
Where ${\bf 1}_N$ is the column vector of $N$ ones.

Comment: thanks, seems to work(With the sum starting at k= 1?).

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a typo on page 10 after eq. 84 [article](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2013/308616.pdf) where $\nabla \varphi$ should be $\nabla \cdot\varphi$ and in fact in the [preprint](http://netlizama.usach.cl/Cuevas-Lizama-Soto(AAA)(2013).pdf) at page 19 we find "*$\nabla \cdot\varphi$ represents the divergence of
$\varphi$*". They only use $\nabla \cdot\varphi$, never $\nabla \varphi$.
So I suppose the use as definition $\nabla \cdot\varphi=\sum_{\nu}\partial_\nu u$.

Comment: Yes this seems very reasonable! I thought with the square it works but it doesnt. Yours works really fine and could be the explanation. Thank you! I just saw that mathreadler  answered my question earlier, anyway thank you looking in the preprint!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional comments first. If one looks close in their paper they say divergence to $\nabla u$ without dot. But anyway, I think I found an answer, at least satisfactory enough for me. I dont know what the authors exactly mean but after reading several other papers which are cited by the authors, I think they maybe could mean $\nabla \cdot u := |\nabla u|^2$ which is the same as $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n (\partial_{x_i} u)^2$. I never saw this notation before so I am not sure if they mean this but anyhow it works just fine for me.

Comment: I was wrong with the square I think, it should be like in mathreadler  and alexjos answer